How to apply transform to root of Rigify
I made a motion capture of dance with video and after Wonder Dynamics.
I transferred the animation to a character to work with Rigify.
I'm having some issues with certain parts of the animation and the feet are moving a bit when they shouldn't.
I corrected some parts of animation with the position of the root bone. The character therefore no longer makes X/Y translations which he should not but the feet are not fixed on the ground although they should.
Is it possible to apply translation transformations as for an object on the root bone?
So that I can then erase the key points and secure the feet to the ground?
thank you very much and best regards

This sounds like the XY Problem. I find it a bit hard to know exactly what you are trying to do, clear examples and why not even a demo file would be helpful here. Maybe you could just correct the animation using layers from the NLA editor?

My approach would be to somehow capture the foot bones’ movement in the global space, then invert it, and apply it to the armature as a whole. But how to convert their forward kinematics into baked keyframes on an empty is the question I have. Can an object constraint be baked to keyframes?

I just transfert all keyframes from root to object ... arf ... sometime need a break ! thank you
